# how can i resolve this 'Push rejected, failed to compile Python app. ! Push failed' error in heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

i am getting this build error while deploying on heroku
can anyone  tell why is this error happened ?

```
      Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
           Collecting pyttsx3==2.90
             Downloading pyttsx3-2.90-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
           Collecting pytz==2021.1
             Downloading pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
           ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==300 (from -r /tmp/build_7bcad96a/requirements.txt (line 99)) (from versions: none)
           ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==300 (from -r /tmp/build_7bcad96a/requirements.txt (line 99))
     !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
     !     Push failed
```

my requirements.txt has

```
    asgiref==3.4.1
    beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
    bs4==0.0.1
    certifi==2021.5.30
    charset-normalizer==2.0.4
    Django==3.2.7
    django-phone-field==1.8.1
    djangorestframework==3.12.4
    djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
    djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.8.0
    docutils==0.17.1
    gunicorn==20.1.0o
    idna==3.2
    Kivy==2.0.0
    kivy-deps.angle==0.3.0
    kivy-deps.glew==0.3.0
    kivy-deps.sdl2==0.3.1
    Kivy-Garden==0.1.4
    Pygments==2.10.0
    PyJWT==2.1.0
    pypiwin32==223
    pytz==2021.1
    pywin32==301
    requests==2.26.0
    soupsieve==2.2.1
    sqlparse==0.4.1
    termcolor==1.1.0
    urllib3==1.26.6
    whitenoise==5.3.0
    setuptools==0.7.3
```

is it just because of python or something else..?
any solutions pls..

Comment: I'm afraid you can't install pywin32 on a Linux machine..

Comment: so what's the solution for this..?

Comment: You may install it on any windows server, Heroku doest have windows hosting.